# Setup questions - samba, zfs on linux, ACLs

Tags: windows, ubuntu, acl, zfs

I am having issues with ACLs with the setup I currently use. We are attempting to allow permission changes from the Windows side of a Samba share.

The samba share is on a server running ubuntu 12.04, with a ZFS filesystem. This was setup through the ZFSonLinux application.

I was wondering if anybody else has this sort of setup and has it working, so that I know im not going down an impossible route. Are ACls possible with this setup, chiefly, does ZFSonLinux support ACLs at all?

Thanks,